# how to compute homology with local coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $S^1$ be a circle.

Let $\pi: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow S^1$ be a covering map.

Let $\rho: \pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow O(n)$ be an orthogonal representation.

Let $\pi_1(S^1)$ act on $C_*(\mathbb{R})$ from right by deck transformation.

Let $\pi_1(S^1)$ act on $\mathbb{R}^n$ from left by $\rho$.

Define the $\rho$-twisted chain complex

$C_*(\mathbb{R})\otimes_{\pi_1(S^1)} \mathbb{R}^n$.

Question.  Is the homology of the $\rho$-twsitec chain complex always trivial for any $\rho$?

Comment: If you let $\rho$ be the trivial action, I believe the homology should be the homology of $S^1$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so nontrivial.

Comment: Have you tried writing out what this complex actually looks like for some simple $\rho$?